# undetected chromedriver quit issue

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

/// options ...
driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
/// actions ...
driver.quit()
```

After the quit the browser close
but in task manager I see the chrome app also so it not quit
the selenium work properly but the undetected chromedriver is not closing

how can I terminate the running process?

thank you in advance!

```
driver.quit()
```

totally close the browser. not just the visible, the running task also which after that is still running as seen in task manager

Answer (score 0):

You can use `taskkill` command in powershell.

```
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
```

Comment: no need for Powershell here (it works OK in a "Command Prompt")